# ListSearchExtender control

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

I try to use this ajax control

```
  <ajax:ListSearchExtender  ID="lseregiondrop" runat="server" TargetControlID="regiondrop"
  PromptPosition="Top" QueryPattern="Contains" PromptText="[Select Region]">
</ajax:ListSearchExtender>
```

when i bulild error shows

```
The control with ID 'lseregiondrop' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it
```

now when i place script manager like this

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

<asp:DropDownList ID="regiondrop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="regiondrop_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>


<ajax:ListSearchExtender  ID="lseregiondrop" runat="server" TargetControlID="regiondrop"
  PromptPosition="Top" QueryPattern="Contains" PromptText="[Select Region]">
</ajax:ListSearchExtender>

 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

when i build this shows error

```
Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'DropDownList'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close `ScriptManager` tag:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```